# How does zp.midpass.ru save data in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html

Run by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs (mid.ru), the web-site https://zp.midpass.ru/ lets one fill in various information in order to get a passport, and then print out all of these details right from the browser, along with a QR code to bring to the consulate, which supposedly has every single piece of information from the form encoded within it.

They claim that none of the operations, other than the passport photo upload, are performed through their server, and all data is saved locally.  (E.g. anyone can try it out, without having to register etc.)

However, they don't seem to require any specific browser versions or anything, seemingly working everywhere.

How does it all work?  Where do they save all of this data?  Is there a way to export it, and import it into another browser / computer, other than printing it outright?

Comment: Why would they need to store the data? You fill in a form, click a button and some JavaScript code computes a hash out of all the data for the QR code. It then populates the DOM with that same data and generated QR code and displays it when you print it (CSS media print maybe?).

Comment: no, they let you save it between the sessions

Answer (score 2):

They use Local Storage. Using Chrome Developer Console I can go to the Resources tab and see that it stores that data using Local Storage after I click on "Save unfiled profile" - Google Translate.

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to show up anywhere in SeaMonkey...  (Or, at least, can't find where!)

Comment: Try with this extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/foundstone-html5-local-storage/